# Screen resolution problems on Thinkpad E520

Tags: configuration, backtrack, resolution

I'm having some troubles with screen resolution.
First of all, I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad E520, with BackTrack 5 R2 installed.

My natural resolution is 1366x768, but I'm stuck with 1024x768.
This is my hardware:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Interl Corporation 2nd Generation Core 
Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

How can I fix that?
Is there a ready-to-use driver or I have to compile that from source?
At least, is there a solution, at all? :(

This is the output of `xrandr` command:

```
Screen 0: minimum 1024x768, current 1024x768, maximum 1024x768   
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    1024x768            0.0*
```

Comment: Please paste here output of "xrandr" command.

Comment: Look like that you have started X with VESA driver. You need to start X with intel driver. Please check the X configuration and log file for the same

Answer (score 1):

I have found this guide on official backtrack forums: [[GUIDE] Loading the i915 driver in the 3.2.6 kernel without adding unsupported PPA's](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=48904)